# My code is creating chart in ppt and working fine with apache poi 4.0.1 but need to make it compatible with 3.9 and have compilation issue on it

Tags: apache-poi

I have used the following link for chart creation
[java create a chart in a powerpoint using APACHE POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373942/java-create-a-chart-in-a-powerpoint-using-apache-poi)
which is working fine for apache poi 4.0.1 but I need to work it on apache poi 3.9. Same code has compilation issue on apache 3.9. I want to work it on apache poi 3.9

```
MyXSLFChartShape(XSLFSlide slide, MyXSLFChart myXSLFChart) throws 
Exception {
String rId = "rId" + (slide.getRelationParts().size()+1);
slide.addRelation(rId, XSLFRelation.CHART, myXSLFChart);    
}

private class MyXSLFChart extends POIXMLDocumentPart {
private CTChartSpace chartSpace;
private MyXSLFChart(PackagePart part) throws Exception {
super(part);
}
```

Comment: You can't - those releases are [from 8 years apart!](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.9). You need to upgrade your 3.9 version to something vaguely modern and supported

Comment: Which version I suppose to use to resolve above compilation issue below 4.0.1 and if I need to do code change what code change is required.

Comment: Latest stable version is Apache POI 4.1.0, upgrade everything to that

Comment: My Actual application is on apache poi 3.9 and when I am upgrading it on higher version then there is compilation issue in thousands of classs. So I want to degrade my code at lower version.

Comment: Look through the [Apache POI changelog](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html) and see all the bugs fixed and security issues solved since 3.9. Then upgrade your code!