# create a chart in a powerpoint using APACHE POI and Java from scratch

Tags: java, charts, apache-poi

I tried to create a chart using the code from the following post.
[java create a chart in a powerpoint using APACHE POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373942/java-create-a-chart-in-a-powerpoint-using-apache-poi)

The PPT file is created, but when I access it, I receive a window requesting me to repair it.
Can somebody help me understand what's going on here?

below is the code for reference:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;

import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class CreatePowerPointXDDFChart {
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try (XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow()) {
   
   // create a new empty slide
   XSLFSlide slide = slideShow.createSlide();
   
   // create chart
   XSLFChart chart = slideShow.createChart();
   chart.setTitleText("Test Chart");
   
   // set axis
   XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
   XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
   leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
   leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);

   // define chart data for bar chart
   XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, bottomAxis, leftAxis);

   // add chart categories (x-axis data)
   String[] categories = new String[] { "Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3" };
   String categoryDataRange = chart.formatRange(new org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress(1, categories.length, 0, 0));
   XDDFCategoryDataSource categoryData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(categories, categoryDataRange, 0);

   // add chart values (y-axis data)
   Double[] values = new Double[] { 10.0, 20.0, 15.0 };
   String valuesDataRange = chart.formatRange(new org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress(1, values.length, 1, 1));
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valueData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values, valuesDataRange, 1);
   XDDFBarChartData bar = (XDDFBarChartData) data;
   bar.setBarDirection(BarDirection.BAR);

   // add series
   XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(categoryData, valueData);
   series.setTitle("Series 1", chart.setSheetTitle("Series 1", 1));
   
   // plot chart
   chart.plot(data);

   // set chart dimensions !!Units are EMU (English Metric Units)!!
   Rectangle chartDimensions = new Rectangle(
    100*Units.EMU_PER_POINT, 
    50*Units.EMU_PER_POINT, 
    400*Units.EMU_PER_POINT, 
    400*Units.EMU_PER_POINT);
   // add chart to slide
   slide.addChart(chart, chartDimensions);

   // Write the output to a file
   try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("./CreatePowerPointXDDFChart.pptx")) {
    slideShow.write(fileOut);
   }
  }
 }

}
```

I am not sure what to do here. @Axel Richter can you please help on this.

Comment: The `CreatePowerPointXDDFChart.pptx` created by code above opens properly using up to `Microsoft Office 2021`. Will check what problem `Microsoft Office 365` actual has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem.

The `CreatePowerPointXDDFChart.pptx` created by code above opens properly using up to Microsoft Office 2021. And it opens properly using Microsoft Office 365 when created using Apache POI up to version 4.1.0.

The problem is that Apache POI from version 4.1.2 decided to set number format settings to the category axis per default. But it sets an empty string as the number format code. Microsoft Office up to version 2021 is tolerant enough to ignore that empty string number format. Microsoft Office 365 is not as tolerant.

Not clear why, of all things, the category axis has that setting by default. The value axis has not.

But to make it work again, one must repair that incorrect number format setting.

In code above `bottomAxis` is the category axis. That is text and not numbers. So the number format should be `@`, which is text. The `leftAxis` is a value axis. This could have number format `#,##0.00` if set.

So changes to code above:

```
...
   //repair axes number format settings
   if (bottomAxis.hasNumberFormat()) bottomAxis.setNumberFormat("@");
   if (leftAxis.hasNumberFormat()) leftAxis.setNumberFormat("#,##0.00");
...
```

---

Edit Feb 2024:

Microsoft Office 365 Version 2402 now ignores that empty string number format again without throwing errors while opening the office file. And current Apache POI version 5.2.5 now does not use empty strings as number format code. Thus the workaround is not needed anymore.

But of course explicit setting the number format codes is not wrong at all. Thus there is no need to remove the code lines.

Comment: I put a change in POI code that will be part of POI 5.2.5 (should be released in a few weeks) - the main change is https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=rev&rev=1913672

Comment: @PJFanning as per your above fix, it seems like the work around suggested by Alex Richter will still work with your fix as well. Could you please confirm on this? Since POI 5.2.5 is not available yet, I'm planning to use the workaround now (don't want it to break after POI upgrade to 5.2.5 down the line)

Comment: setting the numberFormat explicitly will still work