# Getting error while opening workbook with Bar chart generated with Apache POI in latest version of Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to generate a workbook with Bar chart using example provided in the POI Examples - https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/usermodel/BarChart.java

I am able to open the generated workbook and view the chart without any issues with previous version of Excel, but not with latest version of Excel (2309) on both Windows (2309 Build 16827.20080) and Mac (16.77.1 - 23091703).

With the latest version of Excel, on trying to open the workbook, I get an error message "We found a problem with some content in <file_name>. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."
On clicking Yes, the workbook opens, without the Chart.

I am using Office 365. I can confirm with the previous Excel version 2308, the workbook is opening fine.

I tried upgrading to the latest version of POI v5.2.3, but same issue is observed, the generated workbook is opening on previous version but not on latest version of Excel.

I tried to build same Bar chart manually and compare the xml between the generated and manual workbook (after unzipping the xlsx), but couldn't figure out much.

Has anyone else faced this issue? Any pointers to trouble shoot the issue are welcome.

Comment: It is the same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77131316/create-a-chart-in-a-powerpoint-using-apache-poi-and-java-from-scratch/77135432#77135432. Same solution:  `if (bottomAxis.hasNumberFormat()) bottomAxis.setNumberFormat("@");`

Comment: Thanks. It solved the problem. I have upvoted the answer in the post. 
How did you identify the root cause. Is there a way to check what the issue is when the workbook is being opened ? Any pointers to me to go over to learn more and troubleshoot better next time ?

Comment: All Office Open XML files, such as `*.xlsx` and `*.pptx` are simply ZIP archives. So one can unzip them and have a look into. I looked into the `ppt/charts/chart1.xml` and found the `<c:numFmt sourceLinked="true" formatCode=""/>` in axis XML. And I know that an empty string format code is not correct.