# Error opening document created with Apache POI when containing BAR Chart

Tags: apache-poi, office365, openxml

I successfully created .DOCX files with Apache POI for many months. The files could be opened successfully with all Versions of Microsoft Word.

All of sudden, the files can't be opened with Word 365, when they contain a chart of type "ChartTypes.BAR".
The message of Office 365 simply is, that the file can't be opened.

I performed a OOXML validation - there are no validation errors.

To reproduce the issue, you can simply execute the example code from the Apache POI Website
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/xwpf/usermodel/BarChartExample.java

Or you can try this JUnit Test:

```
@Test
    public void barChartTest() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        String chartTitle = "10 languages with most speakers as first language";
        String[] series = { "countries", "speakers", "language" };

        // Category Axis Data
        List<String> listLanguages = new ArrayList<>(3);

        // Values
        List<Double> listCountries = new ArrayList<>(3);
        List<Double> listSpeakers = new ArrayList<>(3);

        listCountries.add(2d);
        listCountries.add(4d);
        listCountries.add(6d);
        listSpeakers.add(10d);
        listSpeakers.add(12d);
        listSpeakers.add(14d);
        listLanguages.add("A");
        listLanguages.add("B");
        listLanguages.add("C");

        String[] categories = listLanguages.toArray(new String[0]);
        Double[] values1 = listCountries.toArray(new Double[0]);
        Double[] values2 = listSpeakers.toArray(new Double[0]);

        int columnLanguages = 0;
        int columnCountries = 1;
        int columnSpeakers = 2;

        try (XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument()) {
            XWPFChart chart = doc.createChart(6000000, 5000000);

            XDDFChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            bottomAxis.setTitle(series[2]);
            XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
            leftAxis.setTitle(series[0] + "," + series[1]);
            leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
            leftAxis.setMajorTickMark(AxisTickMark.OUT);
            leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);

            final int numOfPoints = categories.length;
            final String categoryDataRange = chart
                    .formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, columnLanguages, columnLanguages));
            final String valuesDataRange = chart
                    .formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, columnCountries, columnCountries));
            final String valuesDataRange2 = chart
                    .formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, columnSpeakers, columnSpeakers));
            final XDDFDataSource<?> categoriesData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(categories, categoryDataRange,
                    columnLanguages);
            final XDDFNumericalDataSource<? extends Number> valuesData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values1,
                    valuesDataRange, columnCountries);
            valuesData.setFormatCode("General");
//          values1[6] = 16.0; // if you ever want to change the underlying data, it has to be done before
//                              // building the data source
            final XDDFNumericalDataSource<? extends Number> valuesData2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values2,
                    valuesDataRange2, columnSpeakers);
            valuesData2.setFormatCode("General");

            XDDFBarChartData bar = (XDDFBarChartData) chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
            bar.setBarGrouping(BarGrouping.CLUSTERED);

            XDDFBarChartData.Series series1 = (XDDFBarChartData.Series) bar.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData);
            series1.setTitle(series[0], chart.setSheetTitle(series[0], columnCountries));

            XDDFBarChartData.Series series2 = (XDDFBarChartData.Series) bar.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData2);
            series2.setTitle(series[1], chart.setSheetTitle(series[1], columnSpeakers));

            bar.setVaryColors(true);
            bar.setBarDirection(BarDirection.COL);
            chart.plot(bar);

            XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
            legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.LEFT);
            legend.setOverlay(false);

            chart.setTitleText(chartTitle);
            chart.setTitleOverlay(false);
            chart.setAutoTitleDeleted(false);

            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output/chart.docx")) {
                doc.write(out);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I'm stuck how to fix this problem. Any suggestions ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77188516/getting-error-while-opening-workbook-with-bar-chart-generated-with-apache-poi-in

Comment: Works ! Thanks a lot. This saved my day !