# Apache poi MS excel corrupt

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I created Bar charts in MS Excel sheet using apache poi(version 4). its working sucessfully in MS version 2013,but when we open the file in "Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2309 Build 16.",it say file corrupted

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77227279/error-opening-document-created-with-apache-poi-when-containing-bar-chart -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77188516/getting-error-while-opening-workbook-with-bar-chart-generated-with-apache-poi-in -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77131316/create-a-chart-in-a-powerpoint-using-apache-poi-and-java-from-scratch/77135432#77135432

Comment: @AxelRichter, Thanks its working .