# Excel files created with Apache POI won't show line chart anymore

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

We're using Apache POI in our web app for "years". Suddenly both new and old files created from our app, won't show the line chart. Right now we're using 5.2.3, but files created this spring, that used to open, won't open anymore neither!? The only "error" I get is in Excel, where it says `Removed part: /x1/drawings/drawing1.xml` (so the everything else looks as it should)

I can see the line chart just fine if I open it in (Apples) Numbers, and even in "Preview" in (Mac) Finder.

The code that (supposed to) generate the chart is:

```
XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, anchorR, 15, anchorR+20);
XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
chart.setTitleOverlay(false);
chart.setTitleText(title);
        
List<Integer> selected = selectedMap.get("integer");
        
XDDFChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
bottomAxis.setTitle("");
        
XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisPosition.LEFT);
leftAxis.setTitle("");

XDDFDataSource<String> ticks_xaxis = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(headerRow, headerRow, startCol, noOfCol));
                
Map<Integer, String> lineNames = new HashMap<>();
int count_=0;
                
XDDFChartData lc = null;
if (!selected.isEmpty()) {
    List<XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double>> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer integer : selected) {
        int datar = startRow + integer;
    data.add(XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(datar, datar, startCol, noOfCol)));
    String lname = sheet.getRow(datar).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
    lineNames.put(count_++, lname);
    }

    lc = chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
        
    for (int d=0;d<data.size();d++) {
        XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> line = data.get(d);
    XDDFLineChartData.Series ser = (XDDFLineChartData.Series) lc.addSeries(ticks_xaxis, line);
    ser.setTitle(lineNames.get(d), null);
    ser.setSmooth(true);
    ser.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.NONE);
    }
    chart.plot(lc);
}
```

There are no issues with the table (there are data where the series are trying to "read") and so on..

I understand that it's hard to see were the problem is since I cannot give you the entire source code, but I'm hoping that someone has had this problem before! I've tried to see if there are some dependencies that messes up anything. So.. any hints, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the current chart problems using Apache POI

[Apache poi MS excel corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77264147/apache-poi-ms-excel-corrupt) -> [Error opening document created with Apache POI when containing BAR Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77227279/error-opening-document-created-with-apache-poi-when-containing-bar-chart) -> [Getting error while opening workbook with Bar chart generated with Apache POI in latest version of Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77188516/getting-error-while-opening-workbook-with-bar-chart-generated-with-apache-poi-in) -> [create a chart in a powerpoint using APACHE POI and Java from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77131316/create-a-chart-in-a-powerpoint-using-apache-poi-and-java-from-scratch/77135432#77135432)

seems to be this:

Apache POI from version 4.1.2 decided to set number format settings to the category axis per default. But it sets an empty string as the number format code. Microsoft Office up to version 2021 is tolerant enough to ignore that empty string number format. Microsoft Office 365 is not as tolerant.

Not clear why, of all things, the category axis has that setting by default. The value axis has not.

But to make it work again, one must repair that incorrect number format setting.

In code above `bottomAxis` is the category axis. That is text and not numbers. So the number format should be `@`, which is text. The `leftAxis` is a value axis. This could have number format `#,##0.00` if set.

So changes to code above:

```
...
   //repair axes number format settings
   if (bottomAxis.hasNumberFormat()) bottomAxis.setNumberFormat("@");
   if (leftAxis.hasNumberFormat()) leftAxis.setNumberFormat("#,##0.00");
...
```

Comment: Wow! Spent my entire day today googling, testing, tinkering.. and this solved it. *Thank you*, you're a star!

Comment: I have the exaclty same error bur my solution was to do a downgrade in the version of the Apache POI library. Instead using the 4.1.2, I changed to 4.1.1 and the problem was solved.