# Create Line Chart using Apache POI 5.2.3

Tags: java, apache-poi, linechart

I'm trying to create an Excel (.xlsx) file that inserts a line chart below a table of data using Apache POI 5.2.3 and jdk 11.
Unfortunately when I open the file I get an error message and the chart is deleted from the sheet.
Taking a code that worked last year for line charts , today this presents the same problem.
Below is the class with the code that generates this error and the related pom.xml.
Does anyone know how to help me removethe error?

part of the pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <poi.version>5.2.3</poi.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-full</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Needed? -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <!-- <version>1.2.17</version> -->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
```

And the Test.java:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisCrosses;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.ChartTypes;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.LegendPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.MarkerStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFCategoryAxis;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartLegend;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSourcesFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFLineChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFNumericalDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFValueAxis;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import it.myfiles.excel.balance.utility.Utils;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
        wb.createSheet("My Test");
        XSSFSheet fonteSh = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        
                XSSFRow row = Utils.takeRow(fonteSh, 0);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            Utils.takeCell(fonteSh, 0, i).setCellValue(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        
        row = Utils.takeRow(fonteSh, 1);
        Utils.takeCell(fonteSh, 1, 0).setCellValue("test1");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            Utils.prendiCella(fonteSh, 1, i).setCellValue(13-i);
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
        XSSFDrawing drawing = fonteSh.createDrawingPatriarch();
        XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0,     0, 4, 12, 11);
        XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
        chart.setTitleText("Title chart");
        chart.setTitleOverlay(false);
        XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
        legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP);
        legend.setOverlay(false);
        XDDFCategoryAxis categoryAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        categoryAxis.setTitle("x");
        XDDFValueAxis valueAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
        valueAxis.setTitle("y");
        valueAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MIN);
        
        XDDFLineChartData data = (XDDFLineChartData) chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, categoryAxis, valueAxis);
        
        XDDFDataSource<String> categorySource = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(fonteSh, new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 1, 12));
        
        XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> source1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(fonteSh, new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 1, 12));
        
        XDDFLineChartData.Series serie1 = (XDDFLineChartData.Series) data.addSeries(categorySource, source1);
        serie1.setTitle("title test",null);
        serie1.setSmooth(false);
        serie1.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.CIRCLE);
        
        chart.plot(data);
        
        //Also added this lines but nothing changes
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).addNewAxId().setVal(categoryAxis.getId());
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).addNewAxId().setVal(valueAxis.getId());
        
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
        String filename = "Test-chart"+new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss").format(new Date())+".xlsx";
        Utils.writeWorkbookOnNewFile(wb, filename);
        System.out.println("END");
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77432090/excel-files-created-with-apache-poi-wont-show-line-chart-anymore/77432631#77432631